# Which exceptions kills your web application in java

Tags: java, exception, jakarta-ee

I have a web application which needs to do some checking before user is allowed to use the application. I want to throw some kind of exception that undeploys or kills the the web application if these checks fails, however I am not sure if there are any exceptions I can throw that kills the web application `RuntimeException()?` or if I have to `System.exit(0)`

What is the correct way to kill/stop a web application by force?

Comment: System.exit(0) will be doing the job

Comment: Whats your reason from wanting to stop the application? What exactly do you want to get stopped anyway?

Comment: I want the maintainers of the JBoss server to see that it fails because they forgot to do some stuff that the application needs to run.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Any exception thrown in the init() method of a servlet that is loaded with  in web.xml will undeploy the web application.

Comment: I cant do that in this example. I have to wait for the application to be fully deployed before I can do my check, and first then I need to force a undeploy or a kill of the web application

Comment: Thanks. I didn't think of this. I can create a workaround and kill throw exception here that will prevent it to be deployed.

Answer (score 3):

e.g. in Tomcat You could give your application access to the manager, and when you want to undeploy your application let it call `http://localhost:8080/manager/undeploy?path=/examples`
I think you could also achieve this through a jmx proxy.

For JBoss you could e.g. look at [jsr-88 implementation](http://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/javadoc/4.0.3SP1/deployment/overview-summary.html)  ( which is being pruned in JEE6 but ... maybe jboss keeps it) or also use JMX (i.e. through RMI or so)

note: undeploying a web application because someone authenticated falsly is strange, any next user will not be able to access the app

note2: And indeed as stated before, calling System.exit in a web container will kill the whole container and thus any other applicaiton running in it.

Comment: Yes, I don't want to kill entire JBoss App server. I just want to kill the app it self

Answer (score 2):

### Assumtion

You sayed

> to do some checking before user is allowed to use the application

sounds to me like a login screen and maybe some additional environmental checking (licensing, os, ...).

### If this is true:

Simply don't let the user log in but give him some hint whats wrong (eg: "Buy a Licence")

### If this is false:

Give us some more informations about the kind of your web application (is it interactive? is it a webservice? ...)

Answer (score 1):

Do not use System.exit(0), this will also kill your container!. A RuntimeException won't stop the application from running also.

I would persist somewhere the result of the check and use it whenever I needed to serve a request.

Comment: System.exit() can be disallowed by the SecurityManager; I would expect web and application containers to do this.